# CSS positions go off when adding text inside the positioned divs?

Tags: html, css

I have this perfectly coded layout: 
http://jsfiddle.net/4Xbc8/

It’s exactly how I want it, but if I add any words inside the `div`s they all go out of position.

I kind of understand how the `div`s work, but I don’t know why content in the `div`s go out of position.

Any idea why?

```
body
{
    background-color: blue;

    width: auto;
    overflow: auto;

    white-space:nowrap;

}

#mainwindow
{
    margin-top: 15px;
    max-height: 600px;
    background-color:black;
    height: 600px;
    width: 3000px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;


}
#search_tile
{
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 50px;
    width: 350px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#timeline_tile
{
    margin: 5px;
    position:relative;
    width: 250px;

    height: 580px;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;

}
#conversations_tile
{
    top: -210px;


    position:relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 375px;
    background-color: gray;
    display: inline-block;
}
#source_tile
{
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 450px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    left: -255px;
}



<div id="mainwindow">                   <!-- main window wrapper -->

    <div id="leftarea" class="leftarea">     <!-- LEFT AREA -->


        <div id="timeline_tile" class="timeline_tile"><div></div></div>
        <div id="conversations_tile" class="conversations_tile"></div>
        <div id="source_tile" class="source_tile"></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Which div(s) specifically are you trying to put text into?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas sorry any of the styled divs like source_tile

Comment: `perfectly coded layout` Obviously it's not perfect if there is an issue... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give `vertical-align: top;` to which your div is going below as you not expect to go below. For your "source_tile" give `vertical-align: bottom;`

See your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4Xbc8/4/)